# Is there an elegant way to create a dictionary of arrays?

Tags: python

I frequently analyse data which has a parent child relationship:

```
data = [
    {'data': 'somedata', 'id': 1, 'parentId': 0},
    {'data': 'somedata', 'id': 2, 'parentId': 1},
    {'data': 'somedata', 'id': 3, 'parentId': 0},
    {'data': 'somedata', 'id': 4, 'parentId': 3},
    {'data': 'somedata', 'id': 5, 'parentId': 3},
]
```

Typically I'll use a loop like this to create a new data structure so I can easily relate parent and child data:

```
for item in data:
    if item["parentId"] != 0:
        if item["parentId"] in parents:
            parents[item["parentId"]].append(item["id"])
        else:
            parents[item["parentId"]] = []
            parents[item["parentId"]].append(item["id"])
```

This produces the following data:

```
print parents
{1: [2], 3: [4, 5]}
```

Is there a more elegant way to create the "parents" data structure?

Comment: you could shorten the first check to `if item["parentID"]:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know, what do you mean by more elegant. If you are writing some parsing script, than it seems that using built in structures is ok. So are you asking about used data structures or your code?

One thing I see is that you can use `setdefault` instead of checking if you have certain key in dictionary:

```
for item in data:
    if item["parentId"] != 0:
        parents.setdefault(item["parentId"], []).append(item['id'])
```

Comment: Thanks, by more elegant I meant not have to do the `if in` part and do basically what you have specified.

Comment: surely the first parameter to setdefault should be `item['parentID']`!?

Answer (score 2):

If your Python version includes `collections.defaultdict` you can do:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def make_parent_dict(data):
    parents = defaultdict(list) # Use empty list for missing entries
    for item in data:
        parent = item['parentId']
        if parent != 0:
            parents[parent].append(item['id'])
    return dict(parents) # Convert back to normal dict

example = [
    {'data': 'somedata', 'id': 1, 'parentId': 0},
    {'data': 'somedata', 'id': 2, 'parentId': 1},
    {'data': 'somedata', 'id': 3, 'parentId': 0},
    {'data': 'somedata', 'id': 4, 'parentId': 3},
    {'data': 'somedata', 'id': 5, 'parentId': 3},
]

>>> print make_parent_dict(example)
{1: [2], 3: [4, 5]}
```

Comment: This is basically the same idea as the `setdefault` solution, but you specify the default value factory function once, rather than having to provide a new default value for every attempt to access the dictionary.